# VBS to check for records in excel and sent email

Tags: email, vbscript

I have a VBS which sends an excel sheet every day to users through outlook. But some days the excel will be empty so i don't want to send the excel sheet, instead a message like "No records found" or some thing like that.
My current VBS script is as below -

```
const cdoBasic=0
schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/" 
Set objEmail = CreateObject("CDO.Message") 
With objEmail 
.From = "xyz@abc.com" 
.To = "abc@123.com"
.CC = "akcg@h.com"
.Subject = "Report (Daily Tracking)"
.Textbody = "blah blah blah"
.AddAttachment "F:\\Monitor_Output\\report.xls" 
 With .Configuration.Fields
.Item (schema & "sendusing") = 2
.Item (schema & "smtpserver") = "mail.xxxx.corp"
.Item (schema & "smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
 End With
 .Configuration.Fields.Update
 .Send
 End With
```

Any help on how to modify this and send just a message instead of whole excel sheet?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: You are not using Outlook, you are using CDOSYS.

Comment: Ya but the mail goes to outlook that's what i mean

Comment: On the receiving side? Or to the sender's Sent Items folder?

Comment: On the receiving side.